# Endless Save Loop in MS Word on Mac

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016, docx

I am currently writing a project report in Microsoft Word but it is not allowing me to save the document. When I cmd-S to save, the save dialog opens, and then re-opens each time I try to save the document. It let me save a pdf version but not any other filetype (.docx, .doc, .rtf etc).

My document is 13 pages long with 10 embedded Word Documents (that I use as codeblocks), and several figures and tables. I am also using Styles.

I saw that someone else had a similar issue, and that he ultimately stopped the error by deleting all of his formulas. Well, I have already done that, and am still encountering the problem.

I would hate to have to start from scratch again, inserting each codeblock and styling everything besides just copying and pasting the text and pictures. Hope someone can help. Thanks!

UPDATE: Solved the problem.
The issue was with one of the embedded Word documents I was using as codeblocks. I copied over each page into a new document until I found the troublesome one. Removed it, re-embedded a new word doc, and voila! Problem solved!

With that said, the accepted answer was very comprehensive and I think will benefit others, even though I ended up taking a different route.

Comment: Have you ever tried to start in safe mode? Exclude interference from some add-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit.

I do not use apple.

1. Remove embedded Word documents until you find the troublesome one.
2. If at work could it be a permissions problem?  Save the document to a different location, a location you have sufficient privileges to use. Take it home / somewhere else.
3. Use Microsoft's free online [editor](https://www.office.com/launch/word?ui=en-US&rs=US&auth=1). If saving to cloud save to local. If saving to local save to cloud.
4. Word hates to share documents.  Start Word in safe mode `winword /safe`. Create a new doc, change Tools - Options - Compatibility tab to an older version of word and save it. Open your problem doc and copy and paste your doc into new doc.   Save with a new name. See if word complains.
5. If you are working on a doc that was created with a newer version of Word than you are using install word's document [converters](https://helpdeskgeek.com/office-tips/convert-older-office-documents-to-newer-format/).
6. Start word in safe mode. `winword /safe` This might disable / enable settings that prevent / enable saving the doc.
7. Without word running make a copy of the file, give it a different name, open it.
8. Tools - Options - (General, Compatibility, Security) tabs. Is there a setting to change that will help?
9. See if [compatibility](https://www.bing.com/search?q=word%202016%20document%20compatibility%20mode) solves your problem.
10. Use [openOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/).
11. Use [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/).
12. Check the file properties. Have permissions changed on the file?